# PrintWriter giving null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, client-server, printwriter

I am trying to build a multiple client single java server model. I'm doing this using threads, so I have one thread per client using `AsyncTask`. Thus, I am creating a client socket and the `PrintWriter` object in the `onCreate()` method using the `CreateClient` class and then every time the `button2` is pressed, I just need to pass the question/text to the server for that particular thread. The problem is, I am getting a `NullPointerException` in the `SendMessage` class.

Here's my Client Actvity:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;

//import statements for client
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

//import statements for client
import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText question;

    //Client sockets
    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    private String toTag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // create client as soon as the activity starts
        CreateClient clientConnection = new CreateClient();
        clientConnection.execute();

        question = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        Button query = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        query.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageButton listen = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        listen.setOnClickListener(this);
        listen.performClick();

    }

    private class CreateClient extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                client = new Socket("Server IP Address", 4444);

                printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    private class CloseClient extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            if(printwriter != null) {
                try {
                    printwriter.write("\n");
                    printwriter.close();
                    client.close(); // closing the connection

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                printwriter.write(toTag); // GETTING NULL POINTER EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE
                printwriter.write("\n"); //delimiter

                printwriter.flush();

            return null;
        }

    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button2:
                if(validate()) //Validate is a function that validates the text
                {
                    toTag = question.getText().toString();

                    //Invoke the execute method of AsynTask, which will run the doInBackground method of SendMessage Class

                    SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                    sendMessageTask.execute();

                }
                else
                {
                    //Toast error msg
                }

                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        CloseClient closeConnection = new CloseClient();
        closeConnection.execute();
    }

}
```

Comment: `printwriter` is obviously null.

Comment: How? I am creating a PrintWriter object while creating the activity. @Kon

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that the line

```
printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
```

isn't being executed in time. Try adding a println or initializing the printWriter somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

`printWriter` Object has not been initialized and it is still `null` which is causing Null Pointer Exception

```
printwriter.write(toTag);// at this line -->
```

So **initialize** `printWriter=new PrintWriter();` before using it

Comment: In my onCreate() method, I'm calling clientConnection.execute(); which is initializing the printWriter for me in this line printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out my client socket wasn't getting created due to outdated DDMS in Eclipse. Something about DDMS not able to create a localhost connection on port 8600. So, as Tyler pointed, my `printwriter = new PrintWriter();` statement wasn't getting executed. I updated DDMS and now it works just fine.